# Preserving full refresh data source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, materialized-view

I have a SQL Server database that gets updated every week with a completely new set of data.

I am currently using two staging databases. A series of view databases are connecting to these and one week the view tables have views that point at one set of tables contained in one of the staging databases and the then the views are altered the other week when the ingest of the refreshed data is complete. Staging tables are truncated before each load. There are 12 tables which range from 50Gb to 100Gb.

This is to avoid people waiting for the lengthy ingest to complete and keeps people working.

Are there any more efficient strategies? In Oracle I would turn a materialised view into a table and then refresh the view once the ingestion was complete.

I don't think there is a similar strategy for SQL Server. I am using SQL Server 2016 enterprise.

Answer (score 3):

[ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql) would allow you to switch in each table when you want to change the "live" table.  The only requirement is to ensure both tables involved in the switch are in the same filegeoup, and have the same structure.

Answer (score 1):

So you just made me realize there's a use case for *static* **Materialized Views** due to the decoupling of dependencies in Oracle, resulting in reduced locking issues in a scenario such as your own. (Though when you refresh a **materialized view** in Oracle, I'm not sure how performant its process is vs loading a second staging table?)

I concur with MBuschi's idea of looking into [**Partitioning**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) and [**Partition Switching**](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/08/24/reloading-fact-tables-with-zero-downtime/) which will allow you maintain just a single table.

Another idea I have that you can use instead of a View to control which Table is the *active* one for end users, you could use a [**Synonym**](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-synonym/) instead. It's not much different than using a View, other than the fact that if the schema of your Tables change, you don't have to worry about managing the change in the **Synonym**, it'll always reference the latest schema of the Table. Is this much different than just doing `SELECT *` in your View?... probably not, but a **Synonym** literally contains no code, it's just a pointer between the name of the **Synonym** to the actual object it references, so less to manage / lighter weight in a sense.

You could also just rely on two tables and when the non-active table is done being loaded with the most recent data you can use [`sp_rename`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to immediately switch the table names around and switch from which one is active and which one is not.

If I think of any other ideas I'll update my answer, but I think MBuschi is pointing you in the right direction on this one.

Comment: Oracle Materialized Views can be made to stay current automatically.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dwhsg/advanced-materialized-views.html#GUID-0702359B-D379-4299-86C4-2958BCD4381D

Comment: @RichardArmstrong-Finnerty Nice, never knew that. I'll update my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could load the data to a staging table, drop the original table, then [rename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql) staging to proper. It would be prudent to [refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshsqlmodule-transact-sql) the module meta data after doing this.

Have the clients connect via [DNS alias](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2663/using-friendly-names-for-sql-servers-via-dns/). Swap alias between the staging databases after refresh. This is limited by how well DNS changes propagate in your environment.

Have both sets of staging tables and the client-facing views in a single database. Do everything else as you do currently. This limits the DB count and eliminates cross-database queries, which are slower.

For my two cents I'd go with full-table partition switches. It's fast, can be implemented in a generic script and is easily reversed if errors arise.